# Method property visibility in bean (is thread safe or not?!)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm just thinking about this. If I have dao bean in spring and that dao bean has a protected/public property "currentSQL". It will be value in this property "visible" for all concurent requests or not ?

Example:

```
@Component
public class FooDAO {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  private String currentSQL;

  public void doSome()
  {
    currentSQL = "Foo SQL query";
   }

  public String getSome()
  {
    return currentSQL;
  }
}
```

Is currentSQL property in that example above safe per request or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on how you set the scope of FooDAO bean.

```
<bean id="fooDAO" class="-" scope="prototype"/>
```

for every access (request) on fooDAO spring creates a new instance of FooDAO. Then it can be considered as Thread-safe, as long as your local threads don't use the same instance of FooDAO. If it is the case, you have to handle thread access with "public synchronized void doSome()"

```
<bean id="fooDAO" class="-" scope="singleton"/>
```

if your bean Singleton, then it's not thread-safe. The singleton instance is shared among your application. If this is the case, then you have to synchronize the method.

Comment: important issue is that your DAO shouldn't have state. It's not a good practice. They provide methods/operations on Persistence Layer. If your singletons have state for example in service layer, you have to ensure that the multiple access on them must be synchronized regardless of whether they have state or not.

Comment: & @danny.lesnik Ah, I thought that :) In my example is small bug, there should be "Repository" annotation instead of "Component". But, that change nothing, Repository is still Singleton scope. And by Spring definition, DAOs should be singleton scope (i hope :) ). It is better then to pass all properties to the methods as arguments ? Or is there a solution to make that property thread safe or request safe. I need this functionality because I need to store some informations which are different for each request.

Comment: Ah, I accidentally deleted my previous comment. This thread looks crazy now :). Ok, as I read in spring manual, it is best practice at all to have state less classes in spring. Ok, I will refactor my DAO class then.

Answer (score 1):

If your bean configuration sets your DAO up as a singleton scoped bean (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes), this object would be shared across your entire application where it is injected and that instance var will not be safe. Please note that singleton scope is the default scope.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. your bean is Singleton scope that means that you have only one instance of the class, but it doesn't mean that it is Thread safe. Singleton scope has nothing to do with Singleton design pattern. You need to take care of thread safety and synchronize access to this property.